# Google play location services requests update while google play is updated

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

I am using Google play location api in my app according to the official toturial [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html), it works good on most devices but I get this messege on my HTC Desire :

[image]

The location API doesnt work on it too, then i pressed on the update button and it brings me to this screen :

[image]

As you can see there is no updates to Google play, so what is it that they want me to do?

Comment: Maybe a stupid reply: did you try to uninstall and re-install gplay services?

Comment: Google Play Service updates in the background - so just wait a bit. You'll get a notification once the update is completed - assuming your HTC device has an Internet connection. Also, if you use a firewall app on your device, you may need to enable Internet connection for Google Play Service.

Comment: @Accollativo yes i did try...

Comment: @ChuongPham i waited few days, nothing goes on in the background.

Comment: @OfekRon: That's too long - it normally takes only a few minutes (if that). If all else fail, uninstall Google Play Service or its update package, reboot your device, then let your device upgrade Google Play, then Google Play Service as per normal. Please check if you have a firewall app installed on the device like **AndroidFirewall**. If you have **AndroidFirewall**, open it and select **WiFi** and/or **Data** (depending on your need), then click **Apply Rules** option.